# Get R styler package to remember settings

Tags: r, formatting, rstudio, r-styler

I am trying to get the r package `styler` to remember a simple alteration to `tidyverse_style()`, i.e.

```r
styler::tidyverse_style(indent_by = 4L)
```

When using the rstudio addin tab `addins > Set style` and inputting the above option, styler remembers to indent by 4 spaces for each tab, but forgets this setting when Rstudio is closed.

If I input the above line in the console, it does not remember the 4L indentation at all, defaulting to 2L.

I have tried caching and that doesn't work, probably because all it is used for is to prevent redundant linting.

```r
> styler::cache_activate()
Using cache 1.9.0 at C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\R\cache\R\R.cache/styler/1.9.0.
> styler::cache_info()
Size:       0 bytes (0 cached expressions)
Last modified:  NA
Created:    2023-01-16 09:57:37
Location:   C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\R\cache\R\R.cache/styler/1.9.0
Activated:  TRUE
```

I have trawled through the [documentation](https://styler.r-lib.org/index.html) and cannot find a simple way to store `styler` settings and call it up everytime Rstudio starts up. It would be silly if the only way to do this is to write a `styler` package and import it with `library(mystyle)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://styler.r-lib.org/reference/styler_addins.html) of the styler package you have to set `styler.addins_style_transformer` in your `.Rprofile`:

> The style transformers are memorized within an R session via the R option styler.addins_style_transformer so if you want it to persist over sessions, set the option styler.addins_style_transformer in your .Rprofile.

Following the example in the docs add e.g.

```
val <- "styler::tidyverse_style(indent_by = 4L)"
options(
  styler.addins_style_transformer = val
)
```

to your `.Rprofile`.